# В чём разница между Convert.ToString(), ToString() и (String)?

Tags: c#

Например есть некая переменная:

```
int temp = 5;
```

Затем:

```
String a = Convert.ToString(temp);
String b = (temp).ToString();
String c = (String)temp;
```

В чём разница между этими выражениями?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Функция `ToString()` (вы забыли скобки) — это не приведение типов, это просто функция, которая для числа даёт его строковое представление.

Функция `Convert.ToString(int)` — это тоже не приведение типов, а функция, которая для числа даёт его строковое представление.

Обе функции `ToString()` и `Convert.ToString()` выдают строковое представление в текущей локали, так что различий быть не должно.

Приведение типов в ваших примерах лишь одно:

```
String c = (String)temp;
```

Это приведение типов не будет работать, т. к. `temp` имеет реальный тип `int`, а не `string`. Это даже не скомпилируется, т. к. компилятор видит, что число типа `int` никаким образом не может быть строкой. Приведение типов не меняет сам объект, оно просто меняет тип ссылки на настоящий тип объекта или какой-то из его базовых типов. (Вы ведь понимаете, что число 123 — это совсем не то же самое, что строка из трёх символов '1', '2' и '3'?)

---

**Уголок <s>зануды</s> пуриста.**

Вызовы `5.ToString()` и `Convert.ToString(5)`, согласно [sourceof.net](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/), являются вызовами

```
Number.FormatInt32(5, null, NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture))
```

и

```
Number.FormatInt32(i, null, NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo)
```

внутреннего класса [`Number`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs) соответственно. Могут ли `NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture)` и `NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo` не совпадать?

Код `NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance` для нашего случая можно упростить до следующего:

```
if (!cultureInfo.m_isInherited)
    return cultureInfo.numInfo ?? cultureInfo.NumberFormat;
return cultureInfo.GetFormat(typeof(NumberFormatInfo)) as NumberFormatInfo ?? CurrentInfo;
```

А код `NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo` — до

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
if (!cultureInfo.m_isInherited && cultureInfo.numInfo != null)
    return cultureInfo.numInfo;
return ((NumberFormatInfo)cultureInfo.GetFormat(typeof(NumberFormatInfo)));
```

В случае, когда `cultureInfo.m_isInherited == false` (то есть, у нас `CultureInfo`, а не производный от него тип), у нас [`cultureInfo.GetFormat(typeof(NumberFormatInfo))`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/cultureinfo.cs,ff34854e5cd5a20d) возвращает `NumberFormat`, так что различий нет.

В случае же, когда у нас не `CultureInfo`, а производный от него тип, у нас код упрощается до

```
cultureInfo.GetFormat(typeof(NumberFormatInfo)) as NumberFormatInfo ?? CurrentInfo;
```

и

```
((NumberFormatInfo)cultureInfo.GetFormat(typeof(NumberFormatInfo)));
```

Разный результат может быть лишь в случае, если переопределённая виртуальная функция `GetFormat` сошла с ума, и возвращает разные типы при разных вызовах.

```
class WeirdCultureInfo : CultureInfo
{
    public WeirdCultureInfo() : base("en-US") { }
    bool flag = false;
    public override object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        object result = flag ? (object)DateTimeFormat : NumberFormat;
        flag = true;
        return result;
    }
}
```